# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 32 input samples and 128 target samples

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am following this tutorial here to do image classification.
Link: [Keras image classification][1]

I expanded the code to 8 classes but I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 32 input samples and 128 target samples
```

My train top model code looks like:

```
def train_top_model():
   train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train', 'rb'))
   train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [2] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [3] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [4] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [5] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [6] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [7] * (nb_train_samples // 8))
   validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation', 'rb'))
   validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [2] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [3] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [4] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [5] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [6] * (nb_train_samples // 8) + [7] * (nb_train_samples // 8))
   train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes = 8)
   validation_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(validation_labels, num_classes = 8)
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
   model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
   sgd = SGD(lr=1e-2, decay=0.00371, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
   model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
         loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          epochs=epochs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
   model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
```

I think what the error is trying to say is that the input should have 128 samples but it's only getting 32. I am not sure about the reason because I am also getting this `Found 128 images belonging to 8 classes.` I think it indicates it successfully get all 128 images.

Can someone please help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras complains that you have 32 images in validation set, while your validation labels consist of 128 elements, because you supposingly forgot to change `nb_train_samples` to `nb_validation_samples`, so to fix it, initialise validation labels with `nb_validation_samples`.